# How to login to a website and retrieve data in VBA when IE is blocked?

Tags: html, excel, vba

In a nutshell: I want to monitor something (a number of KPIs) on a website I use with a profile.

I've seen a variety of examples how to login to a website and retrieve data using VBA and IE. That would have been my go to solution (i.e. login regularly through IE and save cookies, open website with VBA/IE and grab data using HTML elements).

```
Sub GetData()
Dim appIE As Object
Set appIE = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")

With appIE
    .Navigate "URL"
    .Visible = True
End With

Do While appIE.Busy
    DoEvents
Loop

Set allRowOfData = appIE.Document.getElementById("ID")

appIE.Quit
Set appIE = Nothing

End Sub
```

Unfortunately, the website I'm looking to work with is blocking IE and as far as I understand something like this is not possible with Edge.

Are there any alternative solutions (e.g. MSXML)?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

You could try using chromium based engine to do the same.
Puppeteer has both .net and js implementation.

https://github.com/hardkoded/puppeteer-sharp